# What's the appropriate hardware to use VTK-based applications?

Tags: graphics-cards, pc, windows

I am developing applications VTK-based similar to Paraview or those for Windows OS. Currently, I am having trouble with the GPU (NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS) since the screen shows noise (random colored pixels scattered in the screen) and it enforces me to reboot the PC (Intel i7 with 24 GB of RAM) to get rid of that noise.

Since I want to upgrade my workstation (probably purchasing a brand new one) I would like to know your recommendations for this kind of tasks.